# Accessing the OpenShift's Secrets in the application code of Airflow PythonOperator

Tags: airflow, openshift

I'm using Openshift for the deployment of the Airflow. Airflow consists of two pods Airflow webserver and Airflow DB(Airflow meta-database).  I have created secrets that consist of Service account details like username and password.  I want to access those values in my data pipeline.

My secrets Deployment config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name :airflow-service-account
  namespace: CUSTOM_NAMESPACE
type: Opaque
stringData:
user-name : SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_IN_BASE64
service-password: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_IN_BASE64
```

I want to access the `user-name` and `service-password` in the airflow data-pipeline eg:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args ={
  'owner' : 'airflow',
  'start_date': datetime(2022,1,1),
  'depends_on_past' : False
}


def api_calls():
   ''' Want to get the value of user-name and service-password ''' 
    print(user-name)
    return f'Able to access the value of user-name and service-password'


def error_check():
   return f'Error function called'

dag =  DAG("testing_dag", default_args= default_args, schedule_interval= timedelta(days=1))
t1 =  PythonOperator(task_id = "test", python_callable= api_calls,dag=dag)
t2 = PythonOperator(task_id = "test_two", python_callable= error_check,dag=dag)

t1>>t2
```

Any possible way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - in your code read the file that contains the secret in the place where it's mounted.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod

Option 2 - perhaps easier - mount the secret as an environment variable, and read that in your code instead.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables